# TF Command Line Executable not showing up on Jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, tfs, tf-cli

I have installed Jenkins on a Linux Server and I am trying to connect Jenkins to a TFS server. I have the TFS plug-in (4.0.0) installed on my Jenkins and I have also installed the tf command line tool (from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727)) on my Linux server.

[image]

[image]

When I create a new job in Jenkins, I get the TFS options to specify the URL, path, user name etc. I was also expecting the "TF command line executable" option to specify the path of the tf tool in my "Manage Jenkins" options but I am not seeing it. Any pointers on why I am not seeing it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answers it!

From the plugin notes for TFS on Jenkins:

> Ever since release 4.0.0, a TFS command-line client or tool is no
>   longer necessary as all the interaction with the TFS server is done
>   using the TFS SDK for Java. The native libraries needed by the SDK are
>   automatically copied to a sub-directory under the agent user's home
>   folder.